# Why does Array#sort behave differently between OS X and Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby

I read https://8thlight.com/blog/will-warner/2013/03/26/stable-sorting-in-ruby.html and tried to replicate its findings, and I'm getting some interesting results. Is this just amazingly bad luck, or am I on to something?

This is what I get in `irb` on OS X 10.11.6 using `rvm`:

```
2.3.1 :001 > (1..10).map { |a| [rand(2),a] }.shuffle.sort { |a, b| a[1] <=> b[1] }.sort { |a, b| a[0] <=> b[0] }
 => [[0, 7], [0, 8], [0, 4], [0, 6], [1, 9], [1, 1], [1, 10], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 5]]
2.3.1 :002 > (1..10).map { |a| [rand(2),a] }.shuffle.sort { |a, b| a[1] <=> b[1] }.sort { |a, b| a[0] <=> b[0] }
 => [[0, 10], [0, 7], [0, 8], [0, 1], [0, 4], [0, 5], [0, 6], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 9]]
2.3.1 :003 > (1..10).map { |a| [rand(2),a] }.shuffle.sort { |a, b| a[1] <=> b[1] }.sort { |a, b| a[0] <=> b[0] }
 => [[0, 7], [0, 8], [0, 3], [0, 10], [1, 1], [1, 9], [1, 6], [1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 5]]
2.3.1 :004 > (1..10).map { |a| [rand(2),a] }.shuffle.sort { |a, b| a[1] <=> b[1] }.sort { |a, b| a[0] <=> b[0] }
 => [[0, 5], [0, 8], [0, 9], [0, 2], [1, 7], [1, 1], [1, 10], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 6]]
2.3.1 :005 > (1..10).map { |a| [rand(2),a] }.shuffle.sort { |a, b| a[1] <=> b[1] }.sort { |a, b| a[0] <=> b[0] }
 => [[0, 1], [0, 5], [0, 7], [0, 10], [1, 8], [1, 6], [1, 9], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]]
2.3.1 :006 > (1..10).map { |a| [rand(2),a] }.shuffle.sort { |a, b| a[1] <=> b[1] }.sort { |a, b| a[0] <=> b[0] }
 => [[0, 4], [0, 5], [0, 9], [0, 3], [1, 8], [1, 1], [1, 10], [1, 2], [1, 6], [1, 7]]
2.3.1 :007 > (1..10).map { |a| [rand(2),a] }.shuffle.sort { |a, b| a[1] <=> b[1] }.sort { |a, b| a[0] <=> b[0] }
 => [[0, 6], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [0, 5], [1, 10], [1, 7], [1, 8], [1, 9], [1, 1]]
2.3.1 :008 > RUBY_VERSION
 => "2.3.1"
```

These findings match the blog post - the final result is not sorted the way you'd expect, which makes sense because Ruby sorting isn't meant to be stable.

If I ssh into an Ubuntu 16.04 server and run the same code, my arrays appear sorted!

```
2.3.1 :001 > (1..10).map { |a| [rand(2),a] }.shuffle.sort { |a, b| a[1] <=> b[1] }.sort { |a, b| a[0] <=> b[0] }
 => [[0, 2], [0, 4], [0, 6], [0, 7], [0, 8], [0, 9], [0, 10], [1, 1], [1, 3], [1, 5]]
2.3.1 :002 > (1..10).map { |a| [rand(2),a] }.shuffle.sort { |a, b| a[1] <=> b[1] }.sort { |a, b| a[0] <=> b[0] }
 => [[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 4], [0, 5], [0, 6], [0, 8], [0, 10], [1, 3], [1, 7], [1, 9]]
2.3.1 :003 > (1..10).map { |a| [rand(2),a] }.shuffle.sort { |a, b| a[1] <=> b[1] }.sort { |a, b| a[0] <=> b[0] }
 => [[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 6], [0, 10], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 7], [1, 8], [1, 9]]
2.3.1 :004 > (1..10).map { |a| [rand(2),a] }.shuffle.sort { |a, b| a[1] <=> b[1] }.sort { |a, b| a[0] <=> b[0] }
 => [[0, 1], [0, 3], [0, 9], [0, 10], [1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], [1, 7], [1, 8]]
2.3.1 :005 > (1..10).map { |a| [rand(2),a] }.shuffle.sort { |a, b| a[1] <=> b[1] }.sort { |a, b| a[0] <=> b[0] }
 => [[0, 1], [0, 4], [0, 7], [0, 8], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 5], [1, 6], [1, 9], [1, 10]]
2.3.1 :006 > RUBY_VERSION
 => "2.3.1"
```

Is this behaviour expected? Everything I've read indicates that ruby sorting isn't stable and that if you stable sorts matter you should implement something [like this](https://moserei.de/2008/09/18/stable-array-sorting-in-ruby.html). But if there's something funky going on here I'd love to know what it is.

Comment: I'd start by sorting the same array-of-arrays on both systems. Hard to say much when you're working with 12 different arrays.

Comment: MRI starting with 2.2.0 on **robust** operating systems performs a stable sort.

Comment: Possible XY problem: if you want to sort by two elements, Ruby knows how to sort arrays.

Comment: Note: the fact that the Ruby Language Specification / RDoc Documentation / RubySpec does not guarantee that `sort` is stable does *not* preclude `sort` being stable. It only means that `sort` is *allowed* to be unstable and you cannot rely on it being stable. So, even if you test a trillion different arrays on a hundred different platforms on ten different Ruby implementations, and all your sorts appear to be stable, you *still* cannot conclude from that that `sort` is stable. That's the nature of testing: it can only tell you about the *actual* behavior of the *exact* cases that you tested …

Comment: and not the *intended* behavior in *all* cases, including the infinite number of cases you didn't test. When in doubt, always look at the *Ruby Programming Language* book, the RubySpec, the RDoc, the ISO Ruby Programming Language Specification, and the *Programming Ruby* book. Only if you don't find your answer there, can you look at the source code of Rubinius, Opal, TruffleRuby, JRuby, MRuby, and YARV, to see what the current consensus is between implementors.